# SilverStripe Dropdown with Categories and Subcategories

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have 2 custom objects: `Category` and `Subcategory` which are linked.
Each Subcategory has a `CategoryID`.

The structure looks like this:

```
Category1
 - Subcategory 1
 - Subcategory 2
 - Subcategory 3
Category 2
Category 3
```

**What I want to do:**

I have a widget in which I need to have a Dropdown field with the above structure.

I created a custom function and this is all I have right now:

```
function getCategoriesAndSubcategories() {
    $categories = Category::get();
    $cat_array = array();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cat_array[$category->ID] = $category->Title; 
        $subcategories = SubCategory::get()->filter(array('CategoryID' => $category->ID));
        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {  
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is even the right approach to the solution, but this is all I have for now.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Try something and let us know if it errors. Are Categories and Subcategories different classes?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody was able to answer my question (only my grammatical mistakes), I eventually end up creating my Custom Form Field called MultipleGroupedDropdown which has the multiple select ability taken from Listbox + every other functionality of the normal Grouped DropDownfield.

If anybody ever needs this they can contact me and I'll provide them this Field for free.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. Please share your code in your answer to help others with similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way of doing this would be to use the hierarchy extension (the same as pages and security groups).

Hierarchy adds a "children"  method to a class, so a category would have children that are also categories.

If you wanted to use a different class for subcategories,  then Subcategory could extend category.

If you did this, you could also use the TreeMultiSelectField (which supports hierarchy).

I have used this in my catalogue module on categories (https://github.com/i-lateral/silverstripe-catalogue/blob/master/code/model/CatalogueCategory.php).

Hope that helps?

Comment: The problem it's solved but this looks interesting, I'll take a look at this ,maybe it will be helpful in the future. Thank you for your response !

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [`GroupedDropdownField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-GroupedDropdownField.html) to create a drop down field with subcategories that are grouped by their category:

Assuming our `Category` and `Subcategory` classes are as follows:

```
class Category extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(1024)'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Subcategories' => 'Subcategory'
    );
}

class Subcategory extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(1024)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Category' => 'Category'
    );
}
```

We can create a `GroupedDropdownField` as follows:

```
$categories = Category::get();
$subcategoryArray = array();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $subcategoryArray[$category->Title] = $category->Subcategories()->map('ID', 'Title')->toArray();
}

$groupedSubcategories = GroupedDropdownField::create(
    'Subcategories',
    'Subcategories',
    $subcategoryArray
);
```